# Create page loading animation is spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, animation, load

I am building a spring-boot web application that loads data from a database which sometimes takes a few seconds. While a requested page is loading, i want to create a page loader that displays immediately when a page is requested, and disappears once the requested page has finished loading. The front end is built with HTML,  thymeleaf, and a couple of javascript and JQuery scripts. I looked up this example https://bradsknutson.com/blog/display-loading-image-while-page-loads/ but it only displays the loader after the page is done loading then disapppears immediately.

Here is the code i tried:

```
<style>
            .loaderStyle{
                position: fixed;
                left: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 9999;
            }
        </style>

        <div class="loaderStyle">
            <i class="fa far fa-frown fa-spin"></i>
        </div>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function() {
                $(".loaderStyle").fadeOut("slow");
            })
        </script>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: How are you building your frontpage? Which language are you using?

Comment: I am using HTML along with thymeleaf. I also have a couple of javascript and JQuery scripts

Comment: Could you please add some code of what you have tried?